# Recibir un "mal" objeto JSON de un endpoint en Angular

Tags: angular, http-get

Soy nuevo en angular y necesito algo de ayuda.
Estoy intentando usar una api de terceros. El caso es que esta devuelve un objeto con esta estructura:

```
busqueda={"numero":56679,"premio":0,"timestamp":1639760576,"status":0,"error":0}
```

Cuando llamo al endpoint con HttpClient me peta

```
  getNumberResult(n: number){
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:4200/api/ws/np?n=${n}`);
  }
```

.
.
.

```
private loadNumber(n: number){
  this.myService.getNumberResult(n).subscribe(
    () => {
      console.log
    },
    ( error: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
      console.log(error);
      
    }
  );
}
```

La respuesta del endpoint es buena. Pero termina devolviendo un error
La consola muestra:

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: 'busqueda={"numero":7,"premio":0,"timestamp":1639760576,"status":0,"error":0}'}
```

Como se ve, en el campo text, sí que llega el resultado que esperaba. Estoy bastante convencido de que todo viene porque la respuesta del servidor empieza por "busqueda=..."

¿Hay una forma concreta de recoger esta clase de objetos?

Muchas gracias por adelantado :D

Comment: Puedes agregar a tu Petición un `responseType: 'text';`, por que supongo que el json es default e intentara parsearlo siempre que tiene la respuesta

Comment: ¡Es justo lo que quería! gracias

Comment: No olviden colocarlo como respuesta, para que @Radiac pueda aceptarla :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simple, el error indica que tu respuesta no es un Json ya que tiene un caracter que hace que sea incorrecto

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0 at JSON

Si revisas la respuesta es una respuesta JSON incorrecta

```
'busqueda={"numero":7,"premio":0,"timestamp":1639760576,"status":0,"error":0}'
```

debes modificar la API para que retorne ùnicamente:

```
'{"numero":7,"premio":0,"timestamp":1639760576,"status":0,"error":0}'
```

Comment: Sí, es lo que me esperaba. Pero no tengo control del backend. Es un servicio de un tercero

Comment: ok en este caso simplemente reemplaza en la respuesta el valor de  "busqueda=" por una cadena vacìa.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:
Gracias a
Eduardo Jaramillo Licea

En el servicio he añadido al final:  {responseType: 'text'}

```
  getNumberResult(n: number){
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:4200/api/ws/np?n=${n}`, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

Gracias a eso, no salta error por no recibir un JSON. Después, solo tengo que quitar el texto que sobra y pasarlo a json.